# Generator connected direct to an Unused Breaker

Tags: generator

I have a 30 amp generator and want to connect temporality to my breaker control box. I have cut off the main and am off the grid. I have a 60 amp range breaker that is unused as I switch to gas a few years ago. Can I tap into that breaker with my generator and selectively use the needed breakers to power lights home outlets etc. not to exceed the generators capacity? Thx for the feedback

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but not safely nor legally. There are plenty of resources available explaining the risks of doing so and the right way do it. [Here's one](http://instructables.com/id/Easy-Generator-to-Home-Hook-Up):

> This is **dangerous**.
>
> It is an electrical **code violation**.
> It is **illegal** in most places.
>
> It is a **fire hazard**. The power created by your generator is generally greater than the rating for the receptacle, wire and breaker [when connected using a male-male extension cord].
>
> If you don't disconnect your main breaker it **can shock the power company linemen** - and you will get sued.
>
> You can easily get shocked because the male plug prongs are exposed [when connected using a male-male extension cord].

I realize that the statements above refer specifically to the male-male extension cord to an outlet approach, but the legality and risk to linemen points are valid.

> Plus if the insurance company determines that you were negligent or
> reckless in using such a generator connection, they can refuse to pay
> out on any insurance claims that result. The best thing to do is to
> use an approved transfer switch or lockout device. ~[Johnny](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12620/johnny)

Comment: Plus, if a lineman detects power coming from your house, the big loppers come out and you will assuredly be the last on your block to get power after the emergency has passed.

Comment: The "shocking the company man" part is a bit dubitable. If your panel is still connected to the mains, then it means your generator would be trying to power the whole neighborhood. If workers are actually working on the supply lines, they will have them all bonded together with grounded safety links. A transfer switch can fail, installs can be done incorrectly and they *know* that someone might do a stupid thing or two with their generator. Don't do anything stupid, but saying "you'll kill the guy trying to help you" is just scare without basis.